# Importing a rails application on Netbeans from an Ubuntu Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, macos, netbeans, ubuntu

We have a ruby on rails application running on an Ubuntu Sever. When I do an SVN checkout of the application and try to create a Netbeans project, I get and error which says

> Rake task failed with working
>   directory
>   (/users/arkidmitra/NetBeansProjects/Project1)
>   Couldnot find i8n-0.5.0 in any of the
>   sources. Try running Bundle Install.

What is the possible problem? I am running netbeans on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you should run

```
bundle install
```

from the command line in the root of your rails project.
That will install all missing gems. If the command is unknown, you should run

```
gem install bundler
```

first.

Hope this helps.